# Why is my api result returning everything of certain types eg. arrays, objects etc. instead of returning readable data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I am trying to make the api return data that is readable instead of data that is of type certain objects. IS there anything that I am doing wrong?

[image]

I tried to fetch the api be sending a request to google directions api by sending a query of an address that I made before the api call. Keep in mind, when I use the cloud function on the client side, I am able to access the data clearly with everything that I need. I am just having trouble on the server-side. I want to be able to see the details such as the duration, time it takes to get the the destination, the distance, and most importantly the latitude and longitude of the path.

I tried fetching the API and then returning the data by printing it in the console.

[image]

Comment: Your code is returning a JSON object. If you want string data, convert the JSON object to a string. One method is to use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)